# Error 1822 MySQL

Tags: mysql

Me sale este error **1822: failed to add the foreign key constraint.** Missing index for constraint **'alumno_ibfk_1'** in the referenced table **'profesor'** y lo mismo pasa con la tabla practica. He probado lo de ALTER TABLE alumno ADD INDEX(DNI_PROFESOR);con todos los atributos pero no funciona.

**La tabla profesor esta bien y la he puesto antes de crear alumno o práctica:**

```
create table profesor (
DNI_PROFESOR varchar(9) not null,
id_matricula varchar(10) not null,
nombre_profe varchar(20),
apellidos_profe1 varchar(20),
apellidos_profe2 varchar(20),
primary key (id_matricula, DNI_PROFESOR),
foreign key (id_matricula) references coches (id_matricula)
);
```

**El problema es al crear estas dos:**

```
create table alumno (
DNI_ALUMNO varchar(9) not null,
DNI_PROFESOR varchar(9) not null,
nombre_alum varchar(20),
apellidos_alum1 varchar(20),
apellidos_alum2 varchar(20),
importe_pagado varchar(4),
primary key (DNI_PROFESOR, DNI_ALUMNO),
foreign key (DNI_PROFESOR) references profesor (DNI_PROFESOR)
);

create table practica (
DNI_PROFESOR varchar(9) not null,
practica_prof varchar(2) not null,
fechas varchar(10),
horarios_practicas varchar(20) not null,
primary key (DNI_PROFESOR, practica_prof, horarios_practicas),
foreign key (DNI_PROFESOR) references profesor (DNI_PROFESOR)
);
```

**El documento completo:**

```
create database autoescuela;
use autoescuela;

create table sucursales (
id_sucursal varchar(10) not null,
direccion varchar(30),
ciudad varchar(20),
p_contacto varchar(40),
telefono varchar(9),
primary key (id_sucursal)
);

create table coches (
id_matricula varchar(10) not null,
modelo varchar(30),
anyo varchar(4),
danyos varchar(40),
primary key (id_matricula)
);

create table disponen (
id_matricula varchar(10) not null,
id_sucursal varchar(10) not null,
primary key (id_matricula, id_sucursal),
foreign key (id_matricula) references coches (id_matricula),
foreign key (id_sucursal) references sucursales (id_sucursal)
);

create table profesor (
DNI_PROFESOR varchar(9) not null,
id_matricula varchar(10) not null,
nombre_profe varchar(20),
apellidos_profe1 varchar(20),
apellidos_profe2 varchar(20),
primary key (id_matricula, DNI_PROFESOR),
foreign key (id_matricula) references coches (id_matricula)
);

create table practica (
DNI_PROFESOR varchar(9) not null,
practica_prof varchar(2) not null,
fechas varchar(10),
horarios_practicas varchar(20) not null,
primary key (DNI_PROFESOR, practica_prof, horarios_practicas),
foreign key (DNI_PROFESOR) references profesor (DNI_PROFESOR)
);

create table alumno (
DNI_ALUMNO varchar(9) not null,
DNI_PROFESOR varchar(9) not null,
nombre_alum varchar(20),
apellidos_alum1 varchar(20),
apellidos_alum2 varchar(20),
importe_pagado varchar(4),
primary key (DNI_PROFESOR, DNI_ALUMNO),
foreign key (DNI_PROFESOR) references profesor (DNI_PROFESOR)
);
```

Comment: En la tabla `profesor` aparece una referencia a una tabla `coches` que no nos estás mostrando. Considera crear un fiddle completo con todas las tablas implicadas para poder hacer pruebas. Por otro lado, `DNI_PROFESOR` debería tener una restricción del tipo `UNIQUE` en la tabla `profesor` (ya que no es llave primaria) si quieres usarla como llave foránea en otra tabla. De todos modos veo un diseño muy precario: ¿por qué tienes una relación de uno a uno entre alumno y profesor? En ese diseño, un alumno no podrá tener más de un profesor.

Comment: Perdona es mi primera vez aquí, ya está el fiddle completo. Vale lo cambio, en cuanto el porque es porque así me lo pide el ejercicio. Gracias por la ayuda :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema está en que la primary key de la tabla "profesor" es compuesta (dni_profesor e id_matricula), por lo que internamente se creara un índice para esa clave compuesta, no obstante, en la tabla "alumno" solo usas parte de dicha clave primaria y falla.

Hay dos soluciones:

1. Cómo bien dice [A. Cedano](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/29967/a-cedano), añadiendo UNIQUE a la columna DNI_PROFESOR de la tabla profesor.

```html
create table profesor (
DNI_PROFESOR varchar(9) not null UNIQUE,
id_matricula varchar(10) not null,
nombre_profe varchar(20),
apellidos_profe1 varchar(20),
apellidos_profe2 varchar(20),
primary key (id_matricula, DNI_PROFESOR)
);
```

2. Añadiendo id_matricula en la tabla alumno (Completando la primary key de profesor).

```html
create table profesor (
DNI_PROFESOR varchar(9) not null,
id_matricula varchar(10) not null,
nombre_profe varchar(20),
apellidos_profe1 varchar(20),
apellidos_profe2 varchar(20),
primary key (id_matricula, DNI_PROFESOR)
);

create table alumno (
DNI_ALUMNO varchar(9) not null,
DNI_PROFESOR varchar(9) not null,
id_matricula varchar(10) not null,
nombre_alum varchar(20),
apellidos_alum1 varchar(20),
apellidos_alum2 varchar(20),
importe_pagado varchar(4),
primary key (DNI_PROFESOR, DNI_ALUMNO),
foreign key (DNI_PROFESOR, id_matricula) references profesor (DNI_PROFESOR,id_matricula)
```

Answer (score 1):

Como ya dije en mi comentario, la columna `DNI_PROFESOR` debe ser o llave primaria (ella sola) o tener una restricción `UNIQUE`, si la vas a usar como llave foránea en otras tablas.

Si declaras la tabla de este modo el error debería desaparecer:

```
create table profesor (
    DNI_PROFESOR varchar(9) not null,
    id_matricula varchar(10) not null,
    nombre_profe varchar(20),
    apellidos_profe1 varchar(20),
    apellidos_profe2 varchar(20),
    primary key (id_matricula, DNI_PROFESOR),
    foreign key (id_matricula) references coches (id_matricula),
    unique(DNI_PROFESOR)  
);
```